# Android/Kotlin - adding TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT to textview doesn't perform the setOnFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-textinputlayout, lost-focus

i've a problem in android app written in *Kotlin*.

I've a textview that has a *setOnFocusChangeListener* and it worked fine as long as i've added an **EndIconMode**.
Now in my layout i see the *END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT* and this works, **but nothing happens when this textview loses focus**.

How can I made this works?

```
textInputLayout = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.textinputlayouttemplate, null) as TextInputLayout
val textView = CreateUI._TextView(castToField(field), textInputLayout.context)

if (field.validatefield || field.nextpage != 0)
{
    textView.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if (!hasFocus && !GlobalVar.drawerOpened)
        {
            if ((field.mandatory && !textView.text.toString().isNullOrEmpty()) || (!field.mandatory)) {
                if (field.validatefield) {
                    validateField(field.fieldcode, textView.text.toString(), field.nextpage)
                } else {
                    _goToNextPageNo = field.nextpage
                    goToNextPageIfExist()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

textInputLayout.addView(textView, layout_wMATCHPARENT_hWRAPCONTENT)
textInputLayout.layoutParams = layout_wMATCHPARENT_hWRAPCONTENT
textInputLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
textInputLayout.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CLEAR_TEXT
linearLayout.addView(textInputLayout)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant for you but apparently this is because setting the `endIconMode` programatically will currently override onFocusChangeListener.

You will even have issues if you set this property via xml and set your own `onFocusChangeListener`. If you not invoke the previous set listener aswell the clear-icon will perform not as intended.

Either you set it via xml and invoke the default listener or use `endIconMode="custom"` and write your own logic.

Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1015)

Comment: Hi @woodii. I've done a workaround. My app send every data to an API that works directly with sql. So i just added a new column where i specify on which field my app has to focus after the validation. This works fine.